# SQL SUM off of Parameters

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to SUM a user's points based off the number of entries they have VS the value of the entry VS the max number of entries they can have in a week.

It's a journaling system. Every day they enter all the activities they were involved in. IE: biking. They can log it every day, but we only want to give them X points a week per activity.

The tables:

Points - holds a entry of every activity (valueID) per day (the journal entry)

Values - holds all the possible activities they can choose

Users - holds the users involved in journaling

```
valueID, valueName, value, maxWeekValue
1, Biking, 1, 6

pointID, userID, valueID, date_created
1, 16, 1, 2013-05-19
2, 16, 1, 2013-05-20
3, 16, 1, 2013-05-21
4, 16, 1, 2013-05-22
5, 16, 1, 2013-05-23
6, 16, 1, 2013-05-24
7, 16, 1, 2013-05-25

userID, name
16, Braden
```

Journal:
5/19-5/25 = I biked and logged every day. I can only get a max pts of 6 in a week, so it should read my total points as 6.

I need a SQL statement that will take every post, group by value, give a sum of the value*entries if< maxWeekValue.

I can do this in PHP. But I know there's a cleaner method of doing so in mySQL.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT p.valueID,p.date_created,v.valueName,v.value,v.maxWeekValue,SUM(v.value) as sumd 
FROM `points` AS p 
INNER JOIN `users` AS u ON u.id = p.userID
INNER JOIN `values` AS v ON p.valueID = v.valueID
WHERE p.date_created 
BETWEEN SUBDATE(curdate(), 7) 
AND curdate()
```

This calculates the sum correctly, but with no conditional logic to limit it to the maxValue per week.

Can any of you sql wizards provide some assistance before I jump over and just do it with PHP? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.valueID,p.date_created,v.valueName,v.value,v.maxWeekValue, case when SUM(v.value) < v.maxWeekValue then SUM(v.value) else v.maxWeekValue end as sumd 
FROM `points` AS p 
INNER JOIN `users` AS u ON u.id = p.userID
INNER JOIN `values` AS v ON p.valueID = v.valueID
WHERE p.date_created 
BETWEEN SUBDATE(curdate(), 7) 
AND curdate()
```

Comment: This seems to work really well! Thank you! Consider the following: I have biking, and I have entries for swimming. This is only returning 1 row of my biking entries. How can I get it to group each activity and give me a row entry like this is returning?

Comment: You have to group all columns that you want to group and are not summarized column. I dont understand very well what you want, but try something like that. Add this code in the end of your query: GROUP BY p.valueID,p.date_created,v.valueName,v.value,v.maxWeekValue

Comment: Right you are! GROUP BY v.valueID at the end solved it. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Is there a way to make this handle multiple weeks? This works well for the current week, but what about week 4? IE: 4 weeks, I log 7 bike rides, maxWeekValue of 6. My count should be 6*4=24. Not 6. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can just add another variable to your query. 
SELECT ...., ( v.maxweek * :numberOfWeeks ) as maxPeriodValue, Case when sum(v.value) < ( v.maxWeekValue * :numberOfWeeks ) then SUM(v.value) else ( v.maxWeekValue * :numberOfWeeks ) end as sumd ... BETWEEN SUBDATE(curdate(), ( 7 * :numberOfWeeks) ...